# show html code in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

in php I use ckeditor to input text value,now I want to show it to jquery dialog,however, my dialog also show the html code on popup.

how can we show the content of html on popup?

here is my popup.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").click(function(){   
         var value = $(this).attr("value");
         $.post("/news/index.php?r=news/detail&id="+value,function(data,status){             
            if(data != null){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var description = obj.description;
                $('#description').text(description);

                $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                     modal: true,                   
                     buttons: {
                     Ok: function() {
                         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                         }
                     }
                });
            }
         });         

    });
});
```

index.php

```
<div id="dialog-message">
    <table>     
        <tr>
            <td>short Content</td>
            <td id="description"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</div>
```

the text show on dialog:

```
<html> <head> <title></title> </head> <body> <p>test for description</p> </body> </html>
```

in result,there is any ways show the text 'test for description' by html declare in dialog ?

thank you very much

Comment: Use `$('#description').html(description);` instead of `$('#description').text(description);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `html()` instead of `text()`

```
$('#description').html(description);
```

instead of

```
$('#description').text(description);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` will escape HTML characters in order for your HTML to be shown as actual text rather than as markup to be rendered by the browser.

Use `.html()` instead and it should work (although i'd be tempted to strip down the HTML you insert to only insert what is between the `<body>` tags)